# UWP Update Task not triggered on Windows Mobile 10

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-mobile, background-task

### Goal

My goal is to implement an Update Task ([according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-a-background-task-during-updatetask)) that is triggered whenever a UWP app is updated. Everything works as expected on the PC however it does not work on the phone.

### What have I already done?

I believe I have followed the docs mentioned above properly so just to make sure:

I have got an App (Universal Windows) project called MyApp.
MyApp references a Windows Runtime Component (Universal Windows) called MyTasks.
MyTasks project contains a single sealed public class UpdateTask. See the code below:

```
namespace MyTasks
{
    public sealed class UpdateTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        private readonly AppService _appService = new AppService();

        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            // This should run EF core DB migration
            _appService.InitializeDataSource();
        }
    }
}
```

In the Package.appxmanifest file of MyApp's project is specified:

```
<Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.updateTask" EntryPoint="MyTasks.UpdateTask" />
</Extensions>
```

Build number was increased in the `Package.appxmanifest`.

Now when a debug is started right on the local machine (PC) the `Run` method is triggered as soon as the app is deployed and everything is fine. When a debug is started on a mobile device connected via a USB cable the `Run` method is not trigerred.

### Question

How to ensure the `Run` method is triggered whenever MyApp is updated on the phone?

Comment: Have you added reference extension for uwp 10.0.xxxxx mobile

Comment: @ShubhamSahu, I have got a reference to Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP (version 10.0.15063.0) in the MyApp project. Do I need that reference in the MyTasks project as well?

Comment: @ShubhamSahu, I have added a reference to Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP (version 10.0.15063.0) to the MyTasks project as well. Unfortunately it had no effect. The Update task is still not executed on the phone.

Comment: Have you checked this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059456/how-to-debug-a-uwp-updatetask)?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, thanks for the input. Yes, I have already checked that one before. Plus that answer only reiterates what is in the official MS docs which I linked in my question.